# Google Maps overlay message won't stay hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map populated with markers retrieved via AJAX to php server call. On the AJAX return, I loop through each marker and set a onClick listener to open an overlayed map message.

Everything works. The markers show up, the message shows up overlayed when I click on a marker. But after I have clicked to close the message, and I drag or zoom or change the map in any way, the message reappears. It just won't stay hidden.

Another thing I noticed is that if I click on one marker, then click on another, the message will change to the new markers message. But if I drag the map, the message starts to flit between the previous and the current marker's message, until I stop dragging it and it settles down to the current marker's message. I do not know if these problems are related. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
//create map
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: defaultLatLng,
    minZoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map($("div#map_canvas").get(0), mapOptions);

//send ajax requesting markers
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            var markerLat = value.lat;
            var markerLng = value.lng;

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerLat, markerLng),
                map: map        
            });
            marker.id = value.id; //set the marker id

            var markerListener = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event){
                /*****move map position****/
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

                //send ajax requesting data based on id of marker clicked
                $.ajax({
                    ...
                    success: function(data) {
                        //actual message 
                        var html = "<a id='close' href='#'>close</a>" 
                            + "<p>" + data.message + "</p>";
                        setMapMessage(html, map);
                    } //end success for markerListener
                }); //end ajax for markerListener
            });  //end markerListener
        }); //end $.each()
    } //end success for ajax getting all the markers
}); //end ajax for getting all the markers

function setMapMessage(message, map){
    //Create custom message
    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    overlay.draw = function() {
        $("#map_message").html(message).show();
        $("a#close").click(function(){
            $("#map_message").hide();
        });

        //get the coordinates of the map (used to set X and Y of the map_message)
        var mapPosition = $("#map_canvas").position(); 

        var mapContainerX = mapPosition.left;
        var mapContainerY = mapPosition.top;

        $("#map_message").css({
            top: mapContainerY,
            left: mapContainerX 
        });
    };
    overlay.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: what is `$("#map_message")` ?

Comment: $("#map_message") and $("#map_canvas") are divs

Answer (score -1):

I finally figured out a work around. I just set the z-index to -1.

```
$("a#close").click(function(){
    $("div#map_message").hide().css("z-index", -1);
});
```

An in the marker listener onClick, I set the z-index to 5.

```
var markerListener = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event){
    /*****move map position****/
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

    //send ajax requesting data based on id of marker clicked
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data) {
            //actual message     
            var html = "<a id='close' href='#'>close</a>" 
                + "<p>" + data.message + "</p>";
            setMapMessage(html, map);
            $("div#map_message").css("z-index", 5);
        } //end success for markerListener
    }); //end ajax for markerListener
});  //end markerListener
```

Comment: however the flitting of the messages is still a nuisance